# What is the maximum jump increase we can achieve using the impact hammer (aka. Piston Jump) in Unreal Tournament GOTY 99?

Tags: unreal-tournament-99, piston-jump

When shooting with the impact hammer at the ground while jumping to jump extra high, what's the maximum jump increase factor we can achieve (vs. jumping normally)?

[Impact Hammer](http://liandri.beyondunreal.com/Impact_Hammer):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [numbers I gathered a few years ago](http://wiki.beyondunreal.com/Legacy:Movement_Metrics_%28UT%29) suggest that you can either increase the jump distance by over 300% or the jump height by over 700%, depending on how you use the Impact Hammer. For maximum height, aim straight down, for maximum distance aim at an angle so that you can still hit something while doing a running jump.